# How to hide the <scripts> and <link> tags in HTML page using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm currently working in Angular and HTML. I want to make my page more secure so I hide the code and content of the page for that I used Angular directive to hide the code and it's works. In that page `<scripts>` and `<link>` tags are available I need that also hide from the page is there any possibilities for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, It's possible. Try this code.

**scripts.js**

```
function loadJSAtOnload() {
var scripts = [
"/Scripts/Angular.js",
"/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js",
"/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
];

for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    console.log('Loading script ' + scripts[i]);
    var scriptType = document.createElement('script');
    scriptType.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptType.src = scripts[i];
    document.body.appendChild(scriptType);  
}
};
if (window.addEventListener)
    addEventListener('load', loadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent('onload', loadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = loadJSAtOnload;
```

**Style.css**

```
@import url('bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('components.css');
@import url('plugins.css');
```

**Call the files in html page.**

```
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you explain **how** and **why** it works?